# C# accessing a function from a static class outside the calling thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, static

**BACKGROUND:**

I have a class with multiple operations that take more than a couple of seconds to finish. In the meantime I want to update the UI. So normally the BackgroundWorker is the way to go. But for some reason the BackGroundWorker doesn't always work the way I want (example: when I try to use a WebBrowser with events and call the ReportProgress event the BackgroundWorker seemingly crashes).

So I avoid all of this by seperating the Ui from the main thread.

This pseudocode explains it better:

```
public Ui ui;

main
{
    Thread threadUi = new Thread(initiateUi);      
    //Initiate and start Thread

    //Everything I will do from here on will not have any consequences 
    //on my ui.
    //
    //Object Ui can still be publicly accessed, making it possible to 
    //update the user interface.
}
```

Now when I have an instance of class Bar I would make it accessible for the UI like this:

```
public Bar bar1;
public Bar bar2;

main
{
    //
    //other stuff here
    //

    Thread threadBar1 = //New Thread where I call the Bar initializer function
                        //and pass bar1 as parameter.
    Thread threadBar2 = //idem dito, except with bar2 as parameter

    //
    //other stuff here
    //
}
```

With this design I can call bar1 and bar2 from my user-interface with the following function:

```
Program.bar1.someFunction();
```

**PROBLEM:**

Now let's say I have a class called FooHandler. This class has a function that searches for all instances of Foo in a certain FooDepository and other functions to manipulate a Foo-object. This is a static class, because in my case, it doesn't need to have multiple instances.

But if I were to call a function from FooHandler, the function runs in my UI-thread, because that is the calling thread (I am not really sure but I couldn't find any documentation about this subject). So there is a good chance I am about to face the problem I started with.

**QUESTION:**

Is it possible to access the function of a static class without using processing power from the calling thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by calling this function using another thread. If you use .NET 4 take a look at Task object, which will easily solve the issue. If you function return string for example, then you need `Task<string>` that will call your function. Then depending on your logic you will either block until it's finished or do something similar. If you are using .NET 4.5 then it's even easier with async/await.

Comment: I am using .Net 4.0. so I will look into this Task object.

Edit: wow! Is using task as simple as:
Task t = new Task(new Action(()=>{ FooHandler.someFunction() ;}));?

Comment: Yes, it's that easy :) Glad that helped. Please use the generic version of the task though, then you will be able to do t.Result (this will block the thread, so be careful) to return your type. Also you don't need to do new Action, here is an example: Task<string> task = new Task<string>(()=> FooHandler.someFunctionThatReturnsString());

Answer (score 3):

First of all: method scope (where it is defined) has NOTHING to do with program flow. Where method is defined (FooHandler, BarProvider or ThreadX) does not affect where it is called. Actually method is always called in caller's thread.

Because you didn't mention any models, views nor view models and in title says "c#" I'm assuming you talking about WinForms.

In WinForms UI controls needs to be called (updated) from the thread which was used to create them (usually main thread). All the UI controls implement ISynchronizeInvoke interface which is meant to do that. So, instead of regular:

```
progress.Position = 7;
```

you need to call `Invoke`:

```
progress.Invoke(new Action(() => progress.Position = 7), null)
```

as there is a lot of boiler-plate code I wrote a little extension function for myself:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void Synchronize(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        if (control == null || !control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            action();
        }
        else
        {
            control.Invoke(action, null);
        }
    }
}
```

So now you can just:

```
progress.Synchronize(() => progress.Position = 7);
```

(a little bit less typing and easier to read)

Technically, Invoke on ISynchronizeTarget does not really call given action. It just puts a message (good old WM_xxxx) in message queue (but does this in caller's thread) with delegate as argument. Then, if target (control's) thread is processing messages (in its own thread) it gets this WM_xxxx message, calls the delegate (in callers thread - but this time it is UI thread) and returns.

If you need new Thread to call FooHandler, and you don't want to wait use Tasks (it's probably the easiest way):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FooHandler.SearchOrWhatever(...));
```

it won't wait (won't block the UI thread).

Despite all of this being said, don't assume it's done.
Multi-threading is hard. And all those construct which support save you typing, but the hard part is still there: dead-locks, race conditions, starving, etc.

Comment: +1 for 'method scope (where it is defined) has NOTHING to do with program flow' as the first line.